# Play framework 2.4 internationalization and i18n.Messages - Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I follow documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N
and create this code to use i18n.Messages in view:

```
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport
import play.i18n.MessagesApi

class Auth @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport{
  val adminForm = Form(mapping(
    "login" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password" -> nonEmptyText)(Admin.apply)(Admin.unapply))

  def login = Action {
    implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.admin.login(adminForm))
  }
}
```

With this I get compile error

> overriding method messagesApi in trait I18nSupport of type =>
> play.api.i18n.MessagesApi; value messagesApi has incompatible type

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You mixing scala and java api's, import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi instead of play.i18n.MessagesApi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mixing scala and java api's, the packages which start with  `play.api` are reserved for Scala,   import `play.api.i18n.MessagesApi` instead of `play.i18n.MessagesApi`.